# How to delete a row from a table and then insert it to another table

Tags: c#, mysql

I have two tables (`RegisteredTBL` & `EnrolledTBL`). When a user registers a student, all values will go to `RegisteredTBL`, after that it will enable the user to pay the tuition to enroll the student.

After paying (regardless of full payment or installment), what I want is to have the rows inserted in `RegisteredTBL` be deleted and moved to `EnrolledTBL`. How can I do it? I need only the mysql code on how to do it.

I think I can apply it to C#. Help please.

Comment: Why would you use two tables in the first place?  Why not just have one table with a Boolean column set to False for registered and True for enrolled?

Comment: As per your question - Is your RegisteredTBL  & EnrolledTBL are same in structure ?

Comment: If you really want to do it with two tables, are you pulling the data into your C# app and processing it there or do you want to transfer this data between tables completely in the database without pulling data into your app?

Comment: INSERT INTO EnrolledTBL select * from RegisteredTBL where student_name = 'xxx';
DELETE FROM RegisteredTBL  where student_name= 'xxx';

Comment: but good option is setting a flag as said by @jmcilhinney

Comment: you can do this is mysql by using after insert trigger

Comment: Thanks guys, from what I need right now, I'll just add a Boolean column to my first table because if use another table it'll ruin my whole code of enrollment system.

Answer (score 1):

**Consider both table has fields with same datatype and size.**

Insert Operation

```
INSERT INTO EnrolledTBL
SELECT Field1,Field2,Field3,... 
FROM RegisteredTBL
WHERE RegisteredTBL_ID = "your id";
```

Delete Operation

```
Delete from RegisteredTBL where RegisteredTBL_ID="your ID";

//RegisteredTBL_ID is your ID column
```